# Nested iif issue in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

Compilation error for nested iif

```
=IIf(Fields!no_of_employees.Value = max(Fields!no_of_employees.Value,"DataSet1"),"Lime","Gold",
       IIf(Fields!no_of_employees.Value = min(Fields!no_of_employees.Value,"DataSet1"),"Red","Gold"
       ))
```

I was trying to implement nested iif.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your statement, you have passed 4 arguments to the first IIF

To write a normal `IIF` you would do something like

```
=IIF(
     ConditionA=True,
     TrueResult,
     FalseResult
    )
```

When writing a nested `IIF` you would do something like this

```
=IIF(
     ConditionA=True,
     TrueResult,
     IIF(
         ConditionB=True,
         TrueResult,
         FalseResult
         )
    )
```

To fix your code, remove the first instance of `"Gold",`  .

I prefer to use `SWITCH()` instead of nested `IIF`s as I think it's easier to read.
If you want to use `SWITCH()` then you can rewrite your expression as follows.

```
=SWITCH(
   Fields!no_of_employees.Value = max(Fields!no_of_employees.Value,"DataSet1"), "Lime",
   Fields!no_of_employees.Value = min(Fields!no_of_employees.Value,"DataSet1"), "Red",
   True, "Gold"
)
```

The final `True` just acts like an ELSE. You can read more about `SWITCH()` here .

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/expression-examples-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver16#DecisionFunctions